# Magento Redirect to mobile website when on Smart Devices

Tags: redirect, mobile

so I have two websites example.com and example.com/mobile , when a user visits my site on a mobile device or tablets etc I would like for them to be redirected to the mobile.example.com.

I have tried editing my .htacess file but it doesn't seem to have any effect, I have also tried adding a JavaScript in the HTML head misc scripts but to no avail.

anybody have any ideas on how i can achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

Magento has this built-in already:

[image]

- http://www.molotovbliss.com/iphone-magento-theme-compatible-with-android/

---

**UPDATE**:

Apologizes for missing the redirecting portion of your question, most likely you'll want to take a look at something like a lightweight php class to use in your `index.php` to determine such.  If you can avoid the headaches of regular expressions with .htaccess, its always best.

> Mobile_Detect is a lightweight PHP class for detecting mobile devices
>   (including tablets). It uses the User-Agent string combined with
>   specific HTTP headers to detect the mobile environment.
>   http://mobiledetect.net

- https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect
- http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/catalog/product/view/id/16835/

Comment: This is to pull a theme when viewed by a certain device, Not what I wanted, I wanted the site to redirect to a different store.

Answer (score -1):

So after messing around for a few hours, I edited the header.phtml of my theme.

Found the solution here

http://wallydavid.com/simple-php-mobile-website-redirect-code

Thanks

Comment: See my added answer reason for downvote.

Comment: Thanks man but I'm not interested in switching themes.

Comment: apologizes I glazed over this detail, I've updated my original answer, hope it helps.